# Як коректно українською буде "helicopter"? (літальний апарат)

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Упродовж багатьох років чув чимало варіантів перекладу "helicopter" - "гвинтокрил", "гелікоптер", "вертоліт". Вочевидь, "Вертоліт" - то є калькою з російського "Вертолёт".

Які варіанти з наведених можна вживати та може існують ще альтернативні назви?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPD.** Офіційна версія виявилася досить кострубатою, бо не розрізняє поміж гвинтокрилом й вертольотом, а гелікоптера не має зовсім. Тому "офіційна" заміняємо на "версія вікі, що має логічне і лінґвістичне підтвердження".

Офіційна версія наступна:

Гвинтокрил (деякі вказують на польське походження слова "gwint", що походить від нововерхньонімецького "gewinde" - різьба) - це суміш гелікоптера і літака, бо в нього є крила, але є і ґвинти (можна знайти от в цьому законі, наприклад: http://zakon4.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z1926-12). Гелікоптер (який ще називають вертольотом) - це і є отой "helicopter", в якого крил немає.

На словотворі ж громада схиляється до гвинтокрила, наскільки я зрозумів, через те, що все решта для них - запозичення. Вважаю, це той випадок, коли мовна самобутність (віддаленість від обох іноземних варіантів слова) віддаляє нас від самого сенсу описуваних літальних апаратів.

Тому, мабуть, треба, все ж таки, користатися словом "гвинтокрил" для комбінації літака і гелікоптера, а для самого "helicopter" використовувати слова "гелікоптер" або "вертоліт". Я схиляюся до першого, бо мені звучить краще, але тут вже ваша воля.

Comment: Цікаво, що закон каже, що  **Вертоліт** - <...> підтримується в польоті, **головним чином**, за рахунок взаємодії повітря з одним або декількома несучими гвинтами <...>.  **Гвинтокрил** - <...> підтримується в повітрі за рахунок взаємодії повітря з одним або декількома несучими гвинтами.  Тобто вертоліт використовує ще щось (крила?), щоб підтримуватись в повітрі, а про гвинтокрил цього не сказали.

Comment: @SassaNF - «Гвинтокрил є прямим перекладом helicopter» – а хіба «helicopter» перекладається не «равликокрил»?

Comment: @YellowSky геометрична фігура `helix` - це такий гвинт, як у Да Вінчі на ескізах. Перші `гвинтокрили` були моделями з дерева і паперу; можна легко побачити, що вони саме `гвинтокрилі`.

Answer (score 8):

Для того, щоб вдало назвати предмет (переклад — *пере*називання), треба розібратися, що він із себе представляє.

Нижче наведені короткі описи деяких візуально схожих літальних апаратів, які оперують за різними принципами і які треба розрізняти поміж собою.

#### Autogyro

З грецької αὐτός + γύρος, дослівно "що сам обертається".
Вікіпедія: [укр.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%80), [англ.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogyro)
Українською: *автожи́р*, також *автогі́р*, *гіропла́н*, *гірокопте́р*, *ротопла́н*.

Тягу (поступальний рух) забезпечує пропелер (розміщений спереду чи позаду).
Підйомну силу забезпечує горизонтально розміщений гвинт, який **не має** приводу, а вільно обертається під час поступального руху ([авторотація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82))).

#### Gyrodyne

З грецької γύρος + δύναμις (dunamis), дослівно "що обертається від сили".
Вікіпедія: [укр.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB), [англ.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrodyne)
Українською: *гвинтокри́л*.

Від *автожира* відрізняється наявністю крил, як у літака, та наявністю двигуна у несного гвинта.

Тягу так само забезпечує пропелер/-и.
Підйомну силу під час зльоту забезпечує несний гвинт (двигун увімкнено), а під час поступального руху частково забезпечує гвинт у режимі авторотації (двигун вимкнено), частково — крила.

#### Helicopter

З французької hélicoptère, з грецької helix + pteron, дослівно "спіраль + крило".
Вікіпедія: [укр.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82), [англ.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter)
Українською: *гелікопте́р*, також *вертолі́т*.

Від *гвинтокрила* відрізняється відстутністю пропелера/-ів та крил.

Підйомну силу **і** тягу забезпечує несний гвинт (за рахунок нахилу всієї машини вперед/назад).

Для зльоту *автожиру* потрібен розбіг, решта може злітати вертикально.

<sub>Най пробачать мене фахові повітроплавці за можливу єресь :)</sub>

---

Висновки, які можна зробити:

1. *Gyrodyne* і *helicopter* — абсолютно різні апарати, відповідно *гелікоптер* не може бути *гвинтокрилом* <sub>(або ж *гвинтокрил* — *гвинтокрилом* :)</sub>
2. Англомовні терміни (етимологія) так само заплутані, як і наші. У *gyrodyne* гвинт може обертатися від двигуна, але те саме стосується й *helicopter*. Сам же *helicopter* — це не *спіралекрил*, як те [планував да Вінчі](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter#/media/File:Leonardo_da_Vinci_helicopter.jpg).
3. Якби придумувати терміни з нуля, то можна було виробити більш-менш зрозумілу схему на базі *гвинт* (*ротор*): *autogyro* – *гвинтоплан*, *helicopter* – *гвинтоліт*, *gyrodyne* – *гвинтолітоплан*.
4. Оскільки *гвинтокрил* може трактуватися як буквальний переклад *helicopter*, найменшим злом було би пряме запозичення усіх термінів, як то *автоґір*, *ґіродин*, *гелікоптер*.

Comment: +1 за _гвинтоліт_ :)